# With the Apache API, why feeding strings is done line by line ? Any reason?

Tags: c, apache, api, http

I've just starting playing with Apache, and I wanted know.

If I base myself on the tutorial/examples I've found, e.g. mod_example.c or mod_hello.c
the http seems always to be sent line by line:

```
ap_rputs("<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Greetings</TITLE></HEAD></BODY>\n",r);
ap_rputs("<H1>Greetings, Earthling</H1>\n",r);
```

Is it a readability issue, or there are real reasons for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's readability in many cases.

You could send the entire response (HTML, etc.) with `ap_rputs()` if you wanted to.